# do columns in a view that aren't used in a select statement affect performance in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-view

Say I have a view called customer_order_info1. it's code is this.

```
create or replace view    customer_order_info1 as
 select
    co.order_number,
    co.customer_number,
    (select address from customer_info ci where ci.customer_number = 
    co.customer_number) as address
    from customer_orders co;
```

If I do

```
select
order_number,
customer_number
from customer_order_info1;
```

What would the code that it runs in the background look like? Would it omit the address column in the view like this?

```
select
co.order_number,
co.customer_number
from customer_orders co
```

or does it still run the code for the address column in the background and not display it?

Second question is, if the code for the view was this instead.

```
create or replace view customer_order_info2 as
select
co.order_number,
co.customer_number,
ci.address
from customer_orders co join customer_info ci
on co.customer_number = ci.customer_number;
```

If I ran this.

```
select
    order_number,
    customer_number
    from customer_order_info2;
```

What would the sql that it runs in the background look like?

this?

```
select
co.order_number,
co.customer_number
from customer_orders co join customer_info ci
on co.customer_number = ci.customer_number;
```

or this?

```
select
co.order_number,
co.customer_number
from customer_orders co;
```

I am using 12c if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an addenda to William's answer targetted to the scalar query example.  Here the scalar query contains a forced error (ie, divide by zero), but if we do not select the column, we can see that things are OK

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  view  my_view as
  3  select empno,
  4         ename,
  5         ( select d.deptno / 0 from dept d
  6           where  d.deptno = e.deptno ) as problem_col
  7  from emp e;

View created.

SQL> select * from my_view;
select * from my_view
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero


SQL> select empno, ename from my_view;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: Nice, that answers the first part. Wish I could pick both yours and William's, as a combination of the two is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle optimiser is smart enough to eliminate columns that aren't used, if doing so will not affect the query results (that is, if the query is logically the same without them). It can eliminate entire tables and joins if it can guarantee doing so will not affect the results. Whether it does or not will depend on the query and the constraints defined on the tables.

In your example it may be able to eliminate `customer_info` if `co.customer_number` is mandatory and a foreign key with `ci.customer_number` as its parent, because then there must always be exactly one row in `customer_info`.

Demo:

```
create table test_parent
( id integer primary key
, parent_name varchar2(30) not null );

create table test_child
( child_id integer primary key
, parent_id references test_parent not null
, child_name varchar2(30) not null );

insert into test_parent values (1, 'Test parent 1');
insert into test_parent values (2, 'Test parent 2');

insert into test_child values (1, 1, 'Test child 1');
insert into test_child values (2, 2, 'Test child 2');
insert into test_child values (3, 1, 'Test child 3');
insert into test_child values (4, 2, 'Test child 4');

commit;

select c.child_id, c.child_name
from   test_child c
       join test_parent p on p.id = c.parent_id;
```

Execution plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |            |     4 |    64 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| TEST_CHILD |     4 |    64 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding p.parent name requires the join, so the plan changes:

```
 select c.child_id, c.child_name, p.parent_name
 from   test_child c
        join test_parent p on p.id = c.parent_id;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                |     4 |   144 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |                |     4 |   144 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_PARENT    |     2 |    34 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | SYS_C001668561 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |                |     4 |    76 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | TEST_CHILD     |     4 |    76 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit: scalar subquery example - a view uses a table for one column:

```
create or replace view customer_order_info1 as
select ch.child_id
     , ch.child_name
     , ( select pa.parent_name from test_parent pa
         where  pa.id = ch.parent_id ) as parent_name
from   test_child ch;
```

but if I don't use that column in a query of the view:

```
select c1.child_id, c1.child_name
from   customer_order_info1 c1
```

I get this execution plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |            |    82 |  2460 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| TEST_CHILD |    82 |  2460 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(No access of `test_parent`.)

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. I specifically wanted how the select statement. "select
order_number,
customer_number
from customer_order_info;" would perform on the two views I described above, one which has an inline select to get the column, and one which has a join. Your example is a little bit different than this, as it is tables, and no columns generated on the fly.

Comment: It's the same principle. I built the simplest case but there will be others.

Comment: It might be the same as the second view in my example, but I cannot be sure of that, and it isn't the same as the first view.

Comment: This will be easier if you add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: After thinking about it more, it does answer the second part of my question, assuming a view works the same.

Comment: I can't create your view because you haven't posted your table definitions. But once you have done that and checked the execution plan you will have answered your own question.